# How to calculate probability of events in a group

Tags: probability

I have a dataset that contains research data about physical activity behaviour. This dataset could be represented by this simplified table:

```
+--------------+-------+-------------+
|   Subject id | Event | Probability |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
| bus driver   | sit   |         0.5 |
| bus driver   | stand |         0.2 |
| bus driver   | walk  |         0.3 |
| postwoman    | sit   |         0.2 |
| postwoman    | stand |         0.2 |
| postwoman    | walk  |         0.4 |
+--------------+-------+-------------+
```

I have a subject id, an event, and a probability of occurrence of that event for this subject. A combination of `<subject id, event>` is unique. Sum of probabilities for the subject id equals to 1. Subjects perform activities independent of each other.

I have 7200 subjects, and approximately 70-150 unique events per subject. Events vary from subject to subject, due to different physical activity behaviour and abilities. For example, a wheelchair user may not have `stand` behaviour, a sportsperson may have more `active` events, and a bus driver will have more `sedentary` events.

What I have so far is:

```
P(event in the group) = SUM (P(event)) / total number of unique subjects

P(`sit` in a group) = 0.5 + 0.2 / 2 = 0.35 
P(`stand` in a group) = 0.2 + 0.2 / 2 = 0.2 
P(`walk` in a group) = 0.3 + 0.4 / 2 = 0.35
```

How can I calculate probabilities of events in the whole dataset for all subjects - that is what is the probability of sitting/standing/walking in this group?

Comment: Do you know how many bus drivers and postwomen there are, respectively?

Comment: @MattiP. I've added a paragraph about my actual data. It's 7200 subjects and 70-150 different events (behaviours) with probabilities. Thank you. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s say that there are $n$ number of subjects associated with each event. I assume that an event can be hosted by only one subject at a time. The probability given in the dataset is based on frequency by which a particular subject can host an event.

First you have to get the sum of all the probabilities which would give you the quantity which is proportional to the total number of events hosted. Then find the sum of all the probabilities of rows where the even id is equal to the one that you are looking for.

The ratio of the two quantities should give you the probability of the event based on the dataset that you have.

Comment: I think I came up with something like that, apart from the sum of probabilities I used the count of subjects. In my case, this will be the same as sum of probabilities = number of unique subjects (probability of all events for a subject is 1). Thank you.